# ERRO de B.D com portas da aplicação fechadas

Tags: banco-de-dados, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

Tenho um e-commerce e está hospedado na **Configr** e nunca tivemos problemas com ele. Esta semana o site começou a ficar sobrecarregado, mesmo sem tráfego nem nada, chegando até cair várias vezes.

O pessoal do servidor diz que as **portas da aplicação estão fechadas** e me mandaram este artigo: http://ajuda.configr.com/o-que-pode-impactar-no-consumo-de-ram-seu-cloud/

> ATENÇÃO! É importante verificar no código da aplicação se há abertura
>   e fechamento das conexões ao banco de dados. Caso contrário, o consumo
>   tende a aumentar.

Alguém que sabe sobre Banco de Dados poderia me ajudar? Pois eu não sei nadinha

Comment: Qual erro de Banco de Dados está aparecendo?

Comment: @Tony não aparece erro nenhum, o site aparece que está sobrecarregado no site da Configr, como se tivesse um trafego absurdo quando na verdade, não tem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei qual é seu banco de dados e não entendo muito de wordpress, mas...

Uma boa prática de programação é sempre que você criar um objeto, depois de usa-lo você destruir o mesmo para assim liberar memória. O mesmo se aplica para banco de dados, ao instanciar uma conexão com o banco você está consumindo memória e processamento do seu servidor, e deixando-o aberto você está constantemente ocupando essa memória e querendo ou não também gerando alguns "lixos de memória".

Ao meu ver, o certo é sempre que você precisar fazer uma pesquisa(select) ou outra operação como uma inserção(insert) ou atualização(update), você instanciar uma conexão com o banco de dados, executar todas as operações necessárias e em seguida fechar a conexão, assim liberando memória e processamento do seu servidor e também o "lixo de memória"

No seu caso, você deve estar instanciando a conexão com o banco e deixando-a aberta sempre, assim gerando sempre um pouco de "lixo de memória" e outras coisas que estão ficando em memória, pesando no seu servidor e nos processos do mesmo.

"Lixo de memória" me refiro a, por exemplo, dados que a conexão possa vir a criar para otimizar tarefas repetidas, e outras coisas.